# Chaining Observable with Promises for common error handling - Angular

Tags: angular, promise, observable, chaining

I am writing writing an application using the latest version of the Angular framework. I came across a problem - some of my methods return observables, and some return promises.
Is it possible to chain them in order to define a single `catch` block for all requests in the chain? (I mean the way you would normally do with just promises).

Take a look at this code sample:

```
loginToBackendServer(token: string) {
return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
  this.userService.loginUserWithFb().subscribe(backendUser => {
    this.facebookProvider.getBasicUserData().then(profile => {
      let userData = {
        id: backendUser['id'],
        facebookId: profile['id'],
        picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'],
        name: profile['name']
      };
      this.userService.userData = userData;
      this.sharedService.emitUserData(userData);
      this.storage.set("fbAccessToken", token);
      resolve();
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        reject();
      })
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
    reject();
  });
});
```

}

How do I chain the `.subscribe()` and the `.then()` so that I only have one `catch` block instead of having to handle errors separately?

Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm new to observables but can't you call `.toPromise()` on an observable?

Comment: As @FrankModica says, use `.toPromise()`, which should allow you to write`return this.userService.loginUserWithFb().toPromise().then(backendUser => ...).then(profile => ...).catch(error => ...)`. In the catch handler, don't forget to re-throw the error otherwise the returned promise will follow its success path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use a new promise to chain all the response and catch the error in one point. By using `fromPromise` and `concatMap` allow you to chain and keep your code organize (Note that I am using [the pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md), it is highly recommend to do so).

```
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

loginToBackendServer(token: string) {
      this.userService.loginUserWithFb().pipe(
          concatMap(backendUser => fromPromise(this.facebookProvider.getBasicUserData()))
      ).subscribe(profile => {
          let userData = {
              id: backendUser['id'],
              facebookId: profile['id'],
              picture: profile['picture_large']['data']['url'],
              name: profile['name']
          };

          this.userService.userData = userData;
          this.sharedService.emitUserData(userData);
          this.storage.set("fbAccessToken", token);
      }, error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }
```